# JHipster Registry on AWS Kubernetes does not display the Swagger API

Tags: amazon-web-services, jhipster, amazon-eks, jhipster-registry

On my side, I have built two microservices and a gateway with JHipster.

When I build and deploy the docker files on my laptop and I access to the Registry (localhost:8761), I have well access to the Swagger API of my microservices.

However, when I deploy the same docker files on Elastic Kubernetes Service (AWS) by following this process:
 - jhipster kubernetes ...
https://medium.com/@barryvredevoort/deploying-jhipster-microservices-on-aws-eks-elastic-container-service-for-kubernetes-d8ec77f5a9
I do not have the API menu to access the Swagger file with the JHipster registry.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and understand why

Comment: Have you checked that the spring profiles are the same?